# За что отвечает ось "w" в Quaternion?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я заметил, что при создании нового объекта класса Quaternion в конце списка параметров есть параметр "w". За что он отвечает?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0 |  https://habrahabr.ru/post/183908/

Comment: в целом надо несколько статей почитать (или видео посмотреть) о том, что такое кватернион. Ибо иногда с первого раза можно не понять.....и как только вы изучите **что такое** кватернион, тогда вопрос о том, что такое "w" - отпадет

Comment: Это такая же ось как и x, y, z в векторном пространстве с размерностью 3.Только тут у нас X Y Z W.